# USB: Protocol for 3d distance informations

Tags: 3d, usb, distance

I am designing a 3D camera hardware.
Is there a USB protocol or standard implementation for transmitting streams of distance informations? (Voxel information)

Answer (score 1):

in OSI model USB is *physical layer* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29)

maybe you mean if there is a special USB device class for 3D devices or voxel data like USB PTP for transfering images (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol, https://sourceforge.net/projects/libptp/) or USB Mass Storage or USB CDC ACM for emulation serial port,...

in the list of USB classes in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes is no special USB class for 3D vector formats or voxel data ...